# CSS Animate Element Inside DIV

Tags: html, css

The code below draws a circle inside a div. On the div hover the idea is to move the circle to the other edge of the div. My code works but the circle in instantly moving to the other side. I am trying to find a way to animate it moving through the div until it reaches left and then go back.

Which properties can I use to achieve this ?

```css
div {
   border-radius: 26px;
   border: 1px solid;
   height: 45px;
   text-align: right;
   transition: all .4s ease;
}

div:hover {
   text-align: left; 
}

.circle {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 26px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"><span class="circle"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot transition the `text-align` property.

Here's an example using the `left` property:

```css
div {
   border-radius: 26px;
   border: 1px solid;
   height: 45px;
}

div:hover .circle{
   left:calc(100% - 45px);    
}

.circle {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 26px;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  left:0;
  transition: left .4s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"><span class="circle"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right path, but a little off.  First, you want to apply the transition to the element you want to animate-- in this case the `.circle` element. Second, you need to use a property that can be animated using [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).  We will use `transform` as it is more performant than rendering a position property.  This is perhaps not exactly what you are looking for, but should put you on the right path.

```css
div {
   border-radius: 26px;
   border: 1px solid;
   height: 45px;
   position: relative;
   width: 98vw;
}

.circle {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 26px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  transform: translateX(0vw);
}

div:hover .circle {
   transform: translateX(calc(-98vw + 100%));
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"><span class="circle"></span></div>
```

Comment: Beware of vw units; It's unlikely to work in most use cases